# Can't use std::source_location in VS2019

Tags: c++, c++20

Although I am using VS2019 with compiler flag `/std:c++latest`, but I am not able successfully include the header `<source_location>`. The following compile error appears:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'source_location': No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you go in your project's properties, what is the version of CPP your project is set to?

Comment: Do you have version [16.10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170)?

Comment: `<source_location>` seems to require MSVC++ 19.29.  [(comparison)](https://godbolt.org/z/nMT6eWvdq)

Comment: Windows SDK Version: 10.0.18362.0
Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2019 (v142)
C++ Language Standard: Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)

Comment: What does Help->About say about the verson number 16.x?

Comment: @Sebastian It says Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.9

Comment: It is really confusing for me to have tons of versions of different tools in VS: VS's version, toolset's version, compiler's version etc. In my understanding to compile a C++ code we need only one thing: compiler and we shouldn't care about anything else. Why so many versions exists? A person should spend a few days to understand all these stuff. I mean my compiler is set on the latest version of C++ for the project and I should have been able to compile it successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Compiler support for C++20 - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20#C.2B.2B20_library_features)

> | C++20 feature | Paper(s) | GCC libstdc++ | Clang libc++ | MSVC STL | Apple Clang |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) | [P1208R6](https://wg21.link/P1208R6) | 11 |  | 19.29 (16.10)* |  |

[Verified on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MdvPr85hY)